# OAuth request from javascript

Tags: javascript, oauth, sharepoint-online, xero-api

I'm trying to make an OAuth request to the [Xero API](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/api-overview) in JavaScript. The API requires OAuth 1.0a. I want to run the JavaScript on the client's browser, so I would assume I can't use Node.js?

The reason why I want to run it in the client's browser is because it has to run in SharePoint Online which doesn't allow server side code and I prefer not to host a seperate app.

I can make the API calls from server side code using C# (did this just to make sure I could call the API correctly) and now i want to make the same calls in JavaScript.

Is it even possible to do this client side? Please share your thoughts as I'm a bit stuck on how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really do this. It's technically possible, but you'd run into issues with CORS and more importantly it's very insecure.

Because you have to sign your calls with a secret/private key, an entirely client side app basically means handing your secret/private key over to anyone who loads up your app in their browser.

OAuth 2 is on its way (https://xero.uservoice.com/forums/5528-xero-accounting-api/suggestions/2102751-oauth-2-0) which will make these kind of apps viable.

(Full disclosure: I'm an API dev at Xero)